# js switchery check/uncheck without triggering an event

Tags: javascript, switchery

I have a multiple js switchery and I want to checked/uncheck without having them trigger onchange event.
my onchange event has a function calling to the external api thats why i wanted to change state without triggering the event. how can I accomplish that in Javascript? already tried

element = document.getElementById('ID');

element.click()

but it does trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will prevent the default onchange event from triggering.

```
document.getElementById(('ID').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```